# Will ntdll.Kernel32ThreadInitThunkFunction related issues

Tags: c, windows-kernel

Kernel32ThreadInitThunkFunction this global variable is not imported inside ntdll but his value is kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk function This is why? How do PE know that it needs to load kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk when it loads ntdll?

Comment: Can you please read "how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

`Kernel32ThreadInitThunkFunction` is global variable inside `ntdll.dll`. the `ntdll.dll` is only single dll which initially loaded to process from kernel (with exe). this dll must not have any dependencies, any static import. during process initialization `ntdll.dll` , in case this is not CLR image and sub-system is `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI` or `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_CUI` - load *kernel32.dll* , query it for `BaseThreadInitThunk` function and store it pointer in `Kernel32ThreadInitThunkFunction`. it call it just before begin calls dll init routines for initialize terminal server

Comment: OK.Thanks 666666666666666